# Azure Devops Build Verification pipeline field clears itself

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

So, I have had build verification for our repos set up for months and today I had a coworker come to me saying that it wasn't running, and his PR couldn't get to main. Upon further inspection the field for what pipeline to run in the build verification policy for the main branch was empty. I reassigned the build pipeline and saved, however If I refresh the page and go back into the policy the field is empty again. Can anyone provide any insight?
Here is an image of the field in question:
[image]

Also before it is asked, The pipeline exists, so does the yaml file it is associated with, and it can be run independently of the build verification policy on our PRs.
Thanks!

Comment: I just checked our (working) build validation. The field is also empty. Maybe this is a relatively new bug?
Just in case you didn't notice that your `Enabled` switch is set to off: it should be on.

Comment: Turned it off so that people can get their stuff through...lol

Comment: I just checked again and the field is populated when I open the "Edit build policy" panel a second time right after closing it.

Comment: We get this as well, but only the **first** time you look at the build policy. If you cancel it then reopen it, the correct pipeline is shown. I guess it's just a bug in the azure devops UI.